# Event to use after order placed and when order status is changed

Tags: event-observer, order-status

I have a scenario where I need to do some calculation on grand total.

1. When order is placed successfully, fetch order status and do
   something
2. After order is placed, and when order status is changed, fetch order
   status and do something more.

I am using the event `sales_order_place_after` while for second one `sales_order_save_after`.

The issue is for first case event `sales_order_place_after` is working good and calculations are correct. But for second case, I am not able to fetch order status using `sales_order_save_after` when order is being placed successfully.

Order status can be only retrieved when its changed from backend, while I need to get it `after order is placed and/or order is changed.`

Event `sales_order_save_after` is a bit tricky. The first time it's triggered Order is not yet commited to DB, and more to that - it actually doesn't have State and Status set yet.

Am I using incorrect events in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Override magento Mage_Sales_Model_Order using  or
Copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

add define  new event on 
_setStatus function

```
    protected function _setState($state, $status = false, $comment = '',
    $isCustomerNotified = null, $shouldProtectState = false)
{
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_before', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));
    // attempt to set the specified state
    if ($shouldProtectState) {
        if ($this->isStateProtected($state)) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('The Order State "%s" must not be set manually.', $state)
            );
        }
    }
    $this->setData('state', $state);

    // add status history
    if ($status) {
        if ($status === true) {
            $status = $this->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($state);
        }
        $this->setStatus($status);
        $history = $this->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false); // no sense to set $status again
        $history->setIsCustomerNotified($isCustomerNotified); // for backwards compatibility
    }
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_after', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));
    return $this;
}
```

**using two sales_order_status_after and sales_order_status_before you can do your requirement**

or **best way to  do this**
sales_order_save_after  and in this observer if

you get old value then try

```
$oldstatus=$order->getOrigData('status');
$Newstatus=$order->getData('status');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182009/get-product-changes/8184430#8184430

Comment: Does the event `sales_order_save_after` gives me order status ?

Comment: yes.. can you already  try this?

Comment: `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
print_r($order->getData())` takes forever to show results.

Comment: Try  $order->getStatus();

Comment: The event is called when order is being placed. It will give the status after the order is placed successfully and when status is changed from admin, and not while being placed.

Comment: ok, i will chck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16683/discussion-between-jordan-and-amit-bera).

Comment: is there any event which can be used after order is placed and when order status is changed ?

Comment: try this  event sales_order_save_commit_after

Comment: when it will be called ?

Comment: @AmitBera as Jordan said, `sales_order_save_after` is not being called when order is placed. Instead use `sales_order_place_after`

Comment: The function is _setState and not setStatus