# Send email after complete transaction

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

I haven't found the right trigger to nottify my client after the product was confirmed as received.

In other words, I change the Order status to complete, but no email is sent. I've created a new template as usual, but can't figure out how to set the trigger that will send the message automatically when the product I define the order as delivered.

Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: by overriding Mage_sales_Model_Order you can do this , [refer this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33459/41024)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function _setState($state, $status = false, $comment = '',
$isCustomerNotified = null, $shouldProtectState = false){Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_before', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));
// attempt to set the specified state
if ($shouldProtectState) {
    if ($this->isStateProtected($state)) {
        Mage::throwException(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('The Order State "%s" must not be set manually.', $state)
        );
    }
}
$this->setData('state', $state);

// add status history
if ($status) {
    if ($status === true) {
        $status = $this->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($state);
    }
    $this->setStatus($status);
    $history = $this->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false); // no sense to set $status again
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified($isCustomerNotified); // for backwards compatibility }Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_after', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));
return $this;}
```

define you events and listen  to it, override Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Comment: Ok I'll try and I'll let you know if it works...

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSantos it it works well?

Comment: Thanks, It's been a while but it worked like a charm!